# Find the common entries between two files (or) How to count the common entries from a file and print it in the output

Tags: python, text, python-requests, duplicates, repeat

Example

File 1:

Abc1

Abc2

Abc3

Abc1

Abc1

File 2:

Abc1

Abc4

Abc3

Abc1

The program should say abc1 as repeated. It will be good if it can compute how many times it is repeated in file2

should give the Output

for file 2

elements    No. of reps

Abc1      2

Abc3      1

Abc4      1

elements which are Repeatedly entered

Abc1

Abc3

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of occurrence of each element with sorting list or using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
import collections

def get_item_list_from_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fin:
        item_list = [line.strip() for line in fin]
    return item_list

def num_occ_with_counters(item_list):
    return collections.Counter(item_list)

#time_complexity is O(N*log(N))
def num_occ_with_sorting(item_list):
    N = len(item_list)
    sorted_item_list = sorted(item_list)
    curr_item = sorted_item_list[0]
    curr_count = 1
    occ = {}
    i = 0
    for i in range(1, N):
        print(curr_item, curr_count)
        if sorted_item_list[i] != curr_item:
            occ[curr_item] = curr_count
            curr_item = sorted_item_list[i]
            curr_count = 0
        curr_count += 1
    else:
        occ[curr_item] = curr_count
    return occ

def main():
    file1_item_list = get_item_list_from_file("file1.txt")
    file2_item_list = get_item_list_from_file("file2.txt")

    #occ_1 = num_occ_with_counters(file1_item_list)
    #occ_2 = num_occ_with_counters(file2_item_list)

    occ_1 = num_occ_with_sorting(file1_item_list)
    occ_2 = num_occ_with_sorting(file2_item_list)

    # intersection of two files
    print(set(occ_1.keys()).intersection(occ_2.keys()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
data1 = [line.strip() for line in open('filename1')]
data2 = [line.strip() for line in open('filename2')]
file1_dict = dict.fromkeys(data1,0)
for data in data2:
    if data in file1_dict:
        file1_dict[data] += 1
for key in file1_dict:
    if file1_dict[key]:
        print(key, file1_dict[key])
```